# Ruby Mixins in Elixir

Tags: elixir

How to create a mixin in Elixir? -- an entity containing functions which I can include in a module and use those functions.

What's the equivalent of Ruby's mixins in Elixir?

Comment: what is your question? I cant understand

Comment: I have no idea what you asked either, but maybe this will help -> http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html

Comment: @coderVishal, how to create a mixin.

Comment: @johshi in your question you said `I can understand how to create a mixin in Elixir`?

Comment: @coderVishal, typo.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of `__using__` macro in action:

```
# mixin.ex
defmodule Mixin do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def hello do
        IO.puts "Hello World"
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule MyModule do
  use Mixin
end

Interactive Elixir (1.4.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> c "mixin.ex"
[MyModule, Mixin]
iex(2)> MyModule.hello()
Hello World
:ok
iex(3)>
```

If your using Phoenix, you can add the def in your `web/web.ex` file inside the quote definition for the specific component you want to extend. For example, I'll often add a all() function to my models.

```
# web/web.ex 
def MyApp.Web do
  def model do
    quote do
      use Ecto.Schema

      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Changeset
      import Ecto.Query

      def all, do: Repo.all(__MODULE__)
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Note that we don't call them mixins in Elixir.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Mixin is an object concept, there are no objects in Elixir.

If you simply want short names for functions, you can use `import` to allow you to reference functions w/o using the full module name.

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html

There is also the use Macro that you can use to inject code from another Module into your current module. This is probably the closest thing to a Ruby Mixin. See

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/domain-specific-languages.html

for an example of how to use the `__using__` macro.

In addition there are Behaviours and Protocols for functional polymorphism.

Behaviours are for when you want a custom function on the same arguments, Protocols are for when you want the same function to work on different data
types.